# Uncountable null sets in arbitrary measure spaces

Tags: measure-theory

Does every measure space $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ with $X$ and $\Sigma$ uncountable, have an uncountable null set?

Comment: What about the counting measure?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The counting measure on an uncountable set does not have an uncountable null set.

Comment: This is same as bof's comment which was an hour before.

Comment: @coffeemath, I'm sorry but I don't understand why this answer is downvoted. I first upvoted bof's comment and then wrote his comment in an answer to be able to accept this as a solution and close this question. Should I just have thanked bof in the comments and leave the question without answer? I thought 'thanks' were not allowed, even though I would still like to thank bof for his solution..